# What is the way i should test update method?

Tags: java, testing, junit, spring-test

I would like test if my update method saving changes into object passing as path variable, but I stack (value in pet.species didn't change to "gorilla"):

```
@Test
public void updateMethodCanChangeParameters() throws Exception{

when(clinicService.findPetById(1)).thenReturn(one);


 mockMvc.perform(post("/pet/update/{id}",clinicService.findPetById(1))
    .param("species", "gorilla"))
    .andExpect(status().isOk())
    .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/pet/findById/1"));


 assertThat(one.getId(), is (1L));
 assertThat(one.getSpecies(), is("gorilla"));
 assertThat(one.getName(), is("Kajtek"));
}
```

Here before method :

```
@Before
public void setUp () throws Exception {

    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new PetController(clinicService)).build();

    one = new PetBuilder()
            .id(1L)
            .dateOfBirth("2000-10-12")
            .name("Kajtek")
            .species("dog")
            .weight(2000)
            .build();
```

and that looks controller method which I test (just make it straight class is annotated with requestMapping /pet) :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "update/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String update (@Valid @ModelAttribute ("petToUpdate") Pet pet,
                      BindingResult result ) {
    if(result.hasErrors())
        return "pet/update/{id}";

    clinicService.saveAndFlush(pet);

    return "redirect:/pet/findById/{id}";

}
```

I thought when I use the param method, I setting parameters name and value then pass they into object which is keep in model but am I wrong?

Comment: Why would you be wrong? What is the issue?

Comment: Well, the isue is that value didn't change : expected "gorilla", but was "dog"

Comment: What is `one.getSpecies()? Did you query it, _after_ making the change?

Comment: one is object Pet.class which i made in @Before method

Comment: Could you show us the com`@Before` method and the complete test method?

Comment: Please show us the complete source code of the controller method that maps to `"/pet/update/{id}"`.